# Area in front of outdoor stage (Picture included)

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the grassy area where people are sitting called, specifically?

[image]

I am not looking for a general term, like meadow, but for a word to describe an area that is for the purpose of accommodating people watching a show where no seats are available.

> The people were watching from ____

Comment: Usually referred to as an audience enclosure.

Comment: It's a lawn, people can either sit on the grass or bring a collapsible chair with them.

Comment: At the Filene Center, at Wolf Trap, just outside of Washington DC, there’s a grassy area called ***the lawn*** (Cf @Mari-LouA’s comment) although the *lawn* at Filene is behind the enclosed, or in-house, seats, not right up near the stage; still *the lawn* is what I’d probably use unless there’s some reason not to. (US English)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer in a single word but what seems to be generally used when the area is in the open air is '**spectator area**'.

> In the 2007-08 season The FA ran a Respect pilot study in 19 leagues across England and these **spectator areas** had a hugely positive effect on behaviour. *The barriers literally draw the line which parents and spectators should not cross.*

[East Riding FA](http://www.eastridingfa.com/clubs/respect/spectator-areas)

Answer (score 1):

> The people were watching from the **[general admission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seating_assignment#General_admission)** seating area.

"In a general admission (also known as open seating or free seating) scheme, each spectator has a ticket. However, the location from which they will watch the event is determined upon arrival at the venue. General admission is most commonly employed in **seat-less venues, such as outdoor festival shows** and smaller club shows."